# build.gradle file error in Android Studio can't applied main & dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I have problem with `Android Studio` in **build.gradle** after I converted `Eclipse` project to `Android Studio` project.

I spent more than 2 hours finding a solution, with no results!!

**build.gradle code:**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

 dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
 }

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}
```

It **gives**: `Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.`

**Screen Shot**

[image]

Any help will be appreciated ...

Comment: Replace `android` in first line with `com.android.application`

Comment: Yes I tried that already without hope! it can't applied main & dependence

Comment: First line should be `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` - is that what you tried?

Comment: @Tapirboy YES that what I tried !! it it can't applied main & dependence .. and I can't run the project

Comment: @Tapirboy  you can see the attached image !!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about this. Glad you got the answer - I voted both your Q. and the accepted A. up.

Comment: Thanks @Tapirboy ,, sure no need for any sorry thanks again :)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message means that it can't find the plugin at all. In Gradle, you need to tell it where to go to look for plugins, which is different from telling it where to go to resolve module dependencies. Add this block to the beginning of your build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

In projects that Android Studio creates, the New Project wizard will put this in the top-level build file in your project, but based on the screenshot it looks like your project only has a single build file, so there's only one place to put it.

Comment: it works well!! big big THANKS ... But plz should I know gradle language when i want to build my android app?? mm :/ @Scott Barta

Comment: You're going to have to learn Gradle if you want to do much Android Studio development. The UI for it is incomplete, and due to the nature of Gradle and Groovy, it's difficult to put a working UI on it at all.

Comment: mm I don't understand well sorry for that :( !! how can I use it in android project plz? for what i need it? it seems it difficult  to understand gradel process well :( @Scott Barta

Comment: Gradle is the build system for Android Studio, so basic knowledge of it will be helpful for any tasks that affect your project's structure -- adding dependencies, setting up testing, using libraries that require additional build support, that sort of thing.